# Finding the power series of $\frac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I need help finding the power series for this function around $z=1$: $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$$
My attempt to solve this:

We know: $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, so I tried substituting $z=w-1$.$$f(w)=\frac{1}{(w-1)^2}=\frac{1}{1+w^2-2w}\\=\frac{1}{1-(-w^2+2w)}=
\{using\ the\ above\ known\ power\ series\}\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-w^2+2w)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(w(w-2))^n=\{sub.\ z=w-1\}\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(z-1)^n(z+1)^n$$

The answer should be: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n$.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I should go about this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use Taylor expansion?

Comment: Guess Taylor and induction works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another variation:

> \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}&=\frac{1}{\left(1+(z-1)\right)^2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{n}(z-1)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+1}{n}(-1)^n(z-1)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using your trick **but** with $\;z=w+1\;$ and developing about $\;w=0\;,\;\;|w|<1$:

$$\frac1{(1+w)^2}=\left(1-w+w^2-\ldots\right)\left(1-w+w^2-\ldots\right)=$$

$$=1-2w+3w^2-\ldots +(-1)^{n-1}nw^{n-1}+\ldots$$

The above can also be approached as:

$$\frac1{(1+w)^2}=\left(-\frac1{1+w}\right)'=\left(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nw^n\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} nw^{n-1}$$

the last step above being justified since power series can be differentiated elementwise within the radius of convergence.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to the OP, Joanpemo's answer is equal to the one you said you should get after you change the indexing to start at $n=0$. If you write out the first several terms of each series, you'll see that they're exactly the same sum, even though they are written differently.

Comment: Thanks @Joanpemo! But what happens to the minus sign when you differentiate $\frac{1}{1+w} $?

Comment: @ApplePie Thank you. Forgot it...:). Editing now.